# Why need a SMS gateway to send SMS programmatically?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, sms, sms-gateway

I am developing a ASP.net project for Shop.It contain inventory management and customer billing reminder also. At the end of month need to send SMS customers about his transaction.

Before stating to develop that part I need to solve few question.

I saw some articles that says need a SMS gateway (like Ozeki) to send SMS and also I saw some articles 'How to send sms without sms Gateway'

Can I complete my task without SMS gateway ? or is it a mandatory thing.
Actually what is this SMS gateway. IF we can send sms via USB Dongle without it, Why we use a Gateway to send sms ? can't we send SMS with sender name instead of number without SMS Gateway ?

this is very small business and I cannot buy a SMS gateway.Those are very expensive :(

Can someone explain this and help me to solve  this  confusion ...

If you have know the some source with ASP.net (or c#/java) that describe how to send SMS with USB Dongle, please be kind enough to share its link

Thanks in advance

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic. In short, there are two reasons. 1. To send messages using GSM-modem is more expensive, that using gateway. 2. If you'll try to send many messages at a time, communication provider will consider this as a spam, and you'll be blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [wammu/gammu](http://wammu.eu/) to send SMS via a USB dongle. But most ISP's (if not all) do not allow for you to send SMS with a modified sender name, hence the use of SMS gateways. SMS gateways allow you to do a lot more like tracking delivery etc. And also it eliminates the maintenance of USB dongle and wammu/gammu

[Nexmo](https://www.nexmo.com/) & [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sms) are two affordable SMS gateways that offer quite excellent API's

You can find Nexmo API Libraries here https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/pre-built-libraries

Comment: can we build our own SMS gateway ? or is there any free SMS Gateway ?

Comment: @GreenCodes Yes you can build your own SMS gateway using wammu/gammu or even kannel (http://www.kannel.org/) with the use of a USB dongle or a serial modem BUT it will not be free. You will still have to pay for the SMS that you send to your Telecom Provider. To the best of my knowledge there are no FREE SMS gateways as Telecom Service Providers charge for sending SMS. Comparatively services such as Nexmo are cheaper (for most countries i checked the price) as there is no setup or maintenance charge and they charge only for the SMS sent

Comment: You can check their prices at https://www.nexmo.com/pricing/

Comment: I know how ever we have to pay service provider. That is totally OK. but except that is there any payments we have to do after build our own sms gateway ? Do you have any idea how to build our own SMS gateway using wammu/gammu ? if you know, could you please give me a link or document to refer ?

Comment: They have quite a good set of documentations at http://wammu.eu/docs/ just make sure the modem/phone/dongle that you are going to use is supported by the library (http://wammu.eu/phones/) a quick google search led me to https://www.drupal.org/node/1804068 and http://xaintech.blogspot.com/2010/05/build-your-own-sms-gateway-with-ubuntu.html

Comment: Does wammu/Gammu support C# / Java or ASP.net ?

Comment: You can write a wrapper (or there maybe one out there) to communicate with the wammu/gammu server take a look at http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/c/examples.html#sending-sms-message

Comment: jammu - interface JAVA with gammu https://code.google.com/p/jammu/source/checkout

Comment: also take a look at (it's in another language and using google to translate) https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://agung-setiawan.com/series/sms-gateway-menggunakan-gammu-dan-java/&usg=ALkJrhjT0MHd0EIlgPsCG5na360ETzBxig

Comment: I am sorry to bother you friend. I am not  a C++ developer and I am not a expert. So it is very difficult to write my own Wrapper.  Do you know any source  (Free) to build our own SMS gateway using C#,ASP.net or JAVA ?

Comment: No worries :) i am more familiar with PHP libraries as i am a PHP developer so i had to search for the ones i posted, those are what i could find. :/

Comment: So did you build your own PHP SMS gateway using it ? Isn't it possible to send SMS via USB dongle in C# or ASP.net?  I don't want change sender name. it is OK to use its SIM number.

Comment: Yeap but i am using kannel (http://www.kannel.org) for sending SMS and i wrote a PHP API to interface Applications to send SMS. Yes with the use of an SMS Gateway, the gateway is used to communicate with hardware device (send/receive SMS)

Comment: I think i confused you so to make it clear, SMS Gateway is used to communicate directly with the hardware (as in phone/dongle/modem) wammu/gammu and kannel are SMS Gateways. And you use API to communicate with the gateway. So when your application tries to send SMS it will send the request to the API and the API will send the request to SMS Gateway. Hope it clears things :)

Comment: is there a free java API to send SMS? if yes let me know.